# How can I import my BitGo wallet backup into Electrum?

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, bitgo

I went through several similar question poster previously, but couldn't figure out what the issue is. A year ago, I had generated a paper wallet. I am not sure how I can sweep it to my electrum wallet.

On the paper wallet, I have the following values:

1. Backup Key
2. Encrypted wallet password
3. Bitgo public key
4. User key

Electrum, on the other hand, is asking for `Private Keys`. Am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclosure: I'm a software engineer at BitGo.*

Most paper wallets store a single private key and this is what you can easily import with most wallets.

However, it seems that you're holding the recovery sheet for a BitGo wallet. BitGo wallets are based on a 2-of-3 multisignature setup: BitGo holds only one key while the user holds their private key and the backup key is either held by the user or a key recovery service. This way, BitGo never is in control of the users' money, but can provide wallet services and effectuate the policies set by the users.

I would be surprised if Electrum had support to import a multisignature setup off the cuff. ;)

If you've lost access to your [BitGo account](https://www.bitgo.com/login), you can use the [account recovery](https://www.bitgo.com/forgotpassword) on our website. If you don't remember your email address either, you can use our [Wallet Recovery Tool](https://bitgo.github.io/bitgo-recovery-tool/) to sweep the wallet content to a destination address of your choice. To move the funds to your Electrum wallet, you could put one of your receive addresses from Electrum as the destination in the recovery tool.

Comment: I have a similar problem but cannot use the Wallet Recovery Tool.  according to tech support: "There have been multiple versions of recovery key cards. It appears that you have an older one. If you scanned the QR code for the user private key using your phone, it will be either a simple string, or a JSON string that looks something like {"iv:…}. If it is the latter, then there is indeed nothing we can do about it, and you will have to use Wallet Recovery Services to restore your password."

Comment: in our case, it's the latter and we've been advised that Dave at Wallet Recovery Services could help, but he charges a steep 20%.  can you help me figure out how I could brute-force the private key? we have some idea of what the password should have been

Comment: additionally, in this article: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/21ab57/quick_rundown_on_bitgo_keys_please/ mbelshe states: "If you printed the keys, they are printed unencrypted and can be directly imported" -- we printed the keys so I have a feeling we may be able to "directly import" them.  but how?

Comment: @ekkis: I think we can give you some pointers about this, could you please ask a new question so we can properly cover it?

Comment: actually, I've determined that the printout my friend has wasn't made from the website but from the e-mail, which means the private key is encrypted.  now I first have to figure out how to brute-force it.  I'll post that question and leave a link here

Comment: ok, here's that question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62486/bitgo-lost-password-how-to-brute-force - TIA for any guidance you can provide